# can't use fraction as parameter for procedure in oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm writing a *stored procedure* for my project. One of the things the stored procedure needs to do is to update a value. the type of this value is defined as `number(6,3)`.

my stored procedure looks somewhat like this:

```
 create procedure procedure_name(id number, length number)
    as a boolean;
BEGIN
update "tablename" tbl
    set "length" = length
where tbl."id" = id;  

    commit;   
END;
```

Then I call the function like: `execute procedure_name(1, 0.8)`

This gives me a conversion error. I also tried decimal but it still gives a conversion error. I even tried to define the parameter as this: `tablename.columnname%type` but it didn't work

The error I receive is:

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numerieke fout of fout in waarde : character to
>   number conversion error.
>
> ORA-06512: in regel 1
>
> 6502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
>
> Cause: An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error
>   occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to
>   assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an
>   attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
>   declared NUMBER(2).
>
> Action: Change the data, how it is manipulated, or how it is declared
>   so that values do not violate constraints.

One could try to use the following fragment of code to recreate the database:

```
CREATE TABLE "tablename" 
(    
    "id" NUMBER(12,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,  
    "length" NUMBER(6,3)
) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE
```

Does anyone have an idea why this is not working?

Kind regards

### EDIT

Calling the procedure from my application works. Directly calling it in SQL fails but calling the procedure using C# seems to work.
My application runs on ASP.NET Core and I'm mapping the double value with `OracleDbType.Double`

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] including the code for your procedure and the full details of the error.

Comment: I edited it to suit your suggestion.

Comment: In you example, you're passing a single parameter to a function that expects two parameters

Comment: Oracle is funny about the decimal point, try 0.8 and 0,8. The quotes around the table/column name can have surprising consequences, try without. And it is a good convention to name the parameter p_length, then the update is less confusing (set length = p_length)

Comment: @Aleksej I changed it thanks.

Comment: @wolφi Thanks for your suggestion I tried 0.8 and 0,8. Both fail, Unfortunately, the removal of quotes doesn't seem to change the situation.

Comment: Can you please post the create table script? Also, are there triggers on that table?

Comment: @Aleksej I reverse engineered the table and added a create script to the question.

Comment: Is this your full procedure? Is there any trigger at this table?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit this is a minimal example that reproduces the problem. There are no triggers on the table.

Comment: I can reproduce the error, very strange...

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce the error:

```
CREATE TABLE t (n NUMBER);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (10);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p (p_n NUMBER) AS
BEGIN 
  UPDATE t SET n=p_n;
END p;
/

-- ok:
exec p(8/10);
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

-- ok:
DECLARE
  y NUMBER := 0.8;
BEGIN
  p(y);
END;
/
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

--error:
exec p(0.8);

ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
ORA-06512: at line 1
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
*Cause:    An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error
           occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to
           assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an
           attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
           declared NUMBER(2).
*Action:   Change the data, how it is manipulated, or how it is declared so
           that values do not violate constraints.
```

(Oracle 11.2.0.4.0 EE 64bit)

Comment: Surprisingly in `Oracle 12c` what you posted is working absolutely fine. I can able to update correctly as shown in my answer.